# How can I trap errors and interrupts in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, signals, gnu-make, bash-trap

I'm wondering if there's a way to implement `trap` in GNU `make`, similar to that built into `BASH`?

If the user presses `CTRL-C`, or if `make` itself fails (non-zero exit), I'd like to call a particular target or macro.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question, even though what you are doing sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. GNU make’s signal handling already leaves a lot to be desired. From within its signal handler, it calls functions like `printf` that are not safe to be called from within a signal handler. I have seen this cause problems, for example `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` rules don’t always run if `stderr` is redirected to `stdout`.

For example, on a CentOS 7.4 box:

1. Create the following `Makefile`:

   ```
   .DELETE_ON_ERROR:

   foo:
           touch $@
           sleep 10
   ```
2. Open it in `vim` and run `:make`,
3. While it is sleeping, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

Vim/make prints

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
touch foo
sleep 10
^C
shell returned 130

Interrupt: Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Make was sent an interrupt signal, but `foo` still exists.

Comment: Do you have some examples where the `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` does not work ? Is that a bug in make implementation ?

Comment: @HakanBaba Details added.

Answer (score 29):

At this point in time, GNU make doesn't have native support.

There is a reliable workaround however:

```
.PHONY: internal-target external-target

external-target:
  bash -c "trap 'trap - SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; <DO CLEANUP HERE>; exit 1' SIGINT SIGTERM ERR; $(MAKE) internal-target"

internal-target:
  echo "doing stuff here"
```

This catches interruptions, terminations AND any non-zero exit codes.

Note the `$(MAKE)` so cmdline overrides and make options get passed to submake.

On trap:

- clear trap handler (with -)
- do the cleanup
- exit with non-zero exit status, so build automation tools report the failed build.

DELETE_ON_ERROR does NOT work for directories, so this is key for cleaning up after `mktemp -d`, for example

Replace `<DO CLEANUP HERE>` with valid CMD.

Comment: Besides the nested quote in your echo, which of course are illegal, this does not seem to work, at least for what I want to accomplish. How is one is supposed to use it? Suppose my makefile had only one target with a sleep and a touch, like @andrewdotn example (ignore .DELETE_ON_ERROR), how would you modify it to use this workaround?

Comment: Please see edits. echo "doing stuff here" would be the sleep/touch. DO CLEANUP HERE would be something like, echo you pressed ctrl-c

Answer (score 21):

A simplified version of @kevinf’s answer which seems good enough for basic cases:

```
run:
    bash -c "trap 'docker-compose down' EXIT; docker-compose up --build"
```

(This example is for a reason: `docker-compose up` does say

> When
>   the command exits, all containers are stopped.

but it does not `rm` the stopped containers like `docker run --rm` would, so you can still see them with `docker ps -a`.)

Comment: I still see `recipe for target 'run' failed ... make: *** [run] Interrupt` when I try this, and the make target does not run the `docker-compose down` command. (I have the exact use case described in this answer.)

Comment: This did work for me for this exact use case of making sure down runs after up.

Answer (score 2):

Make does not support it, but using BASH tricks you can accomplish something similar.

```
default: complete

complete: do_mount
        echo "Do something here..."

do_mount:
        mkdir -p "$(MOUNTPOINT)"
        ( while ps -p $$PPID >/dev/null ; do \
                sleep 1 ; \
        done ; \
        unmount "$(MOUNTPOINT)" \
        ) &
        mount "$(MOUNTSOURCE)" "$(MOUNTPOINT)" -o bind
```

The "unmount" will run after the "make" completes.  This is usually a satisfactory solution if you are attempting to cleanup operations that may occur during the build but are not cleaned up normally on "make" exit.

Answer (score 1):

No. As far as I know there is no such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

make produces return codes. As far as I can remember right now, it returns 0 for success, 2 for failure (please check the documentation). Therefore, would it be enough for you to wrap make inside a shell script for example?

Comment: I can do that, but trying to avoid it if possible, it's self-contained and I'm *trying* to keep it that way.